# Application does not get mulicast messages on ubuntu os

Tags: ubuntu, udp, multicast

I have an applicaion running on ubuntu 16.04 os.

The application is receive mulicast messages however the application **does not** get the messages.

I can see on wireshark IGMP message that the application register to the multicast address and when I run
netstat -ng on the application computer I also see that the right nic register to the multicast address.

I also see the multicast messages arrived to the computer using tcpdump.

Why the application does not get the multicast messages? Am I missing something?

Comment: Does your firewall allow those incoming packets through?

Comment: Thank for your response. How do i know if firewall block on ubuntu 16.04?